# const char to char problem

Tags: c++

How do I convert from `char` to `const char`? How do I implement type casting without changing the `char SendBuf`? Here is my code:

.cpp

```
// main()    
char SendBuf[6] = "Hello";
sendto(..., SendBuf, ...);

// sendto structure
int sendto(
__in  SOCKET s,
__in  const char *buf,
__in  int len,
__in  int flags,
__in  const struct sockaddr *to,
__in  int tolen
);
```

Error

```
Error   1   error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'const char [6]' to 'char [6]'
```

Thank you.

Comment: That code should not produce that error message.  Maybe you left something relevant out.

Comment: please create the smallest program that you can that still has the problem, and copy and paste that code into your question. Please do not re-type your code, but rather paste the exact text in. In summarizing and retyping your program, you left out an important detail.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Array Assignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5279082/array-assignment)

Comment: @Adams this is my simplest coding what `sendto` from socket parameter should take. i just need to know the correct assignment for my variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write the assignment like this:

```
const char *SendBuf = "Hello";
```

You don't have to do anything about the function call. (A `const char*` parameter will take a `char*` variable as input.)

Comment: The error is in the assignment, not the function call. I'll update.

Comment: what does a `const char` is actually means?

Comment: @Chicko: In a variable declaration, it means it creates a constant variable (can never be written to).  On a pointer, it means the pointer is a read-only view of the memory, but some other part of the program might still change to pointed-to variable.

Comment: @divide: I wouldn't recommend this fix, maybe he needs to write into the buffer before transmitting it.

Comment: @divide: What assignment?  The assignment that's in the real code, but not in the question?  (Your answer and the question both have *initialization*, not *assignment*)

Comment: Actually my buffer would be a dynamic buffer. Means, each time the user needs to specify buffer data before sending. Not just constant variable all the time.

Comment: Your question is related with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6024574/how-to-convert-a-const-char-to-simply-char

Answer (score 4):

I don't have a Microsoft compiler handy to test this theory, but I suspect that the OP has code like this:

```
int main() {
    char SendBuf[6];
    SendBuf = "Hello";
    // sendto(..., SendBuf, ...);
}
```

I suspect that the error he is seeing, `cannot convert from 'const char [6]' to 'char [6]'` is occuring on *assignment*, not initialization nor the `sendto` call.

Can someone with a Microsoft compiler check compile the above program and confirm the error message?

Comment: Yes, repro in Visual C++ 2010.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
char SendBuf[6] = { "Hello" };
```

Note the braces, which tell the compiler you're initializing an aggregate (in this case an array).

And then, instead of

```
SendBuf = "Hello";
```

which is obviously your real code, use

```
strcpy(SendBuf, "Hello");
```

or

```
memcpy(SendBuf, "Hello", 6);
```

Comment: +1: ignores the misleading title & questions resolves the compile error and actual problem ;)

Comment: -1: It is legal to initialize `char[]` with a string. The braces don't tell the compiler anything it doesn't already know.

Comment: @Rob: Well, there's apparently some compiler (probably some older Visual C++) that has a problem with it... actually just tried assignment, since that's what the compiler message talks about, verified that's the issue, and noted you've guessed that as well.

Comment: @Rob: And `char[]` is an exception to the general rule.  Putting braces around array initializers is a good habit for consistency, even if skipping it is specifically allowed for `char[]` (only).

Comment: @Rob: Edited answer to address what is obviously the real code.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason why you can't pass your string literal into the method? `sendTo(...,"Hello",...);`

If yes then why not simple declare `const char* SendBuf = "Hello";` instead of using the char array as one alternative.

Or perhaps better yet start exploring STL and use `std::string SendBuf("Hello");` and pass `SendBuf.c_str()` into the method.

There is always more than one way to skin a cat just pick the knife that is most comfortable for you.

Comment: Yuck.  `std::string` is not really appropriate for storing network packets.  And `c_str` is definitely not, `sendto` doesn't work on the basis of a NUL terminator.

Comment: I wasn't jumping to the conclusion of usage although you're probably right even though OP only asked about conversion and `char` vs `const char` ... the point remains the same use the best tool for the job whatever that may be.