# How to convert a `const char *` to simply `char *`?

Tags: c++, constants

I'm using the pdCurses library and am aiming to only really use strings in my C++ console game but the curses `mvinstr()` function or any insert function requires a non-const `char *` as a parameter.

- My solution at first to this problem was simply entering in `string.c_str()`, but that returns a **`const char *`** which apparently doesn't work with the function.
- Next I put `(char *)string.c_str()` but this only causes an unhandled exception.
- Finally I just tried `char *test = string.c_str()` but that's not compatible with `const` either.

What do I do to solve this?

K i just tried const_cast() and i still get an exception thrown and break....
I don't know why PDcurses only takes non-const char pointers.... =(

alright making a char* buffer didn't work when i used this code (time_s is the sting):

```
size_t length; 
    char buffer[12]; 
    length=time_s.copy(buffer,5,0); 
    buffer[length]='\0';
mvinstr(time_loc_y, time_loc_x, buffer);
```

i even put a stop before mvinstr() and checked the buffer's contents which was "00   /0"
EXACTLY WHAT I WANTED.

but i get an access violation point to "xutility"....

Comment: Take into account that usually its not recommended to remove constness, this has something to do with design flaws.

Comment: Violation accessing what code and where?

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`mvinstr(x,y,str)` and others "take characters (or wide characters) from the current or specified position in the window, and return them as a string in `str` (or `wstr`)."

The function will actually modify the string, so you cannot safely cast the `const` away, especially since `c_str` specifies that you should not modify the returned string.

You need something along the lines of:

```
const MAX = 100;
char buf[MAX];
mvinnstr(x, y, buf, MAX);
...error checking...
string s = buf;
```

Note that I avoided `mvinstr` in favour of `mvinnstr` to avoid the potential for buffer overflows.

Comment: @Griffin, sounds like a buffer overflow, and I specifically showed how you can avoid that. Note: It's not clear whether you should pass MAX or MAX-1 to `mvinnstr`, but that can be determined from testing.

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
char* buffer = &str[0];
int fetched_len = mvinnstr(time_loc_y, time_loc_x, buffer, str.size());
str.resize(fetched_len);
```

In general, though, you should make a writable buffer instead of removing `const` from a pointer that has it.  e.g.

```
vector<char> charvec(MAX_LENGTH);
str = string(&charvec[0], mvinnstr(time_loc_y, time_loc_x, &charvec[0], charvec.size());
```

Comment: C++03 tried to guarantee your first snippet would work (and failed), but it is guaranteed to work in C++0x. In both cases, make sure there's enough reserved memory in the string.

Comment: @GMan: I was trying to avoid looking up the particular API, in order to provide a more general answer, but I've just edited it to prevent overflow.

Comment: Hmm... just realized this is similar to my answer but with the added `resize` call ... might you want to show what you're doing with the `&str[0]` call more explicitly so that the OP doesn't get lost. +1.

Comment: @Billy: That's what I had in an earlier revision, ... I'll see what I can do to emphasize that.

Comment: @Ben: Awesome -- removed my answer because yours is better.

Comment: @GMan: [Technically the standard doesn't require it to work, but there are no known implementations where it does not work.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256160/how-bad-is-code-using-stdbasic-stringt-as-a-contiguous-buffer)

Comment: @Billy: Isn't that what I said?

Comment: @GMan: No -- you said only that C++03 tried to make that the case, but that it didn't. My point is despite the fact that it doesn't, it really doesn't matter. :)

Comment: @Billy: Right, but then I said "make sure the buffer is big enough to pull it off", which implies that it's ok. (Admittedly, reading again I wasn't clear enough about it.)

Comment: @GMan: Hehe -- wasn't saying you were incorrect -- just wanted to be more explicit about it. (And serve my self serving interest of linking to one of my questions ;) )

Answer (score 2):

Cautiously - if the code that uses the was-`const` data tries to modify it, anything can happen.

In short:

```
const std::string str = "...";
char *caution = const_cast<char *>(str.c_str());
```

However, given that you are getting unhandled exceptions, you probably need to make a modifiable copy of the constant string before calling `mvinstr()`.  Maybe:

```
const std::string str = "...";
char *caution = new char[str.length()+1];
str.copy(caution, str.length()+1);
...call to mvinstr()...
delete[] caution;
```

Comment: That's not a `std::string`, content of `std::string` is mutable.

Comment: Does const_cast<char *> act differently than '(char*)'aConst_char_pointer?

Comment: @Griffin: Use backticks to protect code snippets against interpretation of asterisk as formatting codes.

Comment: @Griffin: Yes. C style casts cannot remove `const` -- only `const_cast` can do that. (You should be using C++ style casts anyway)

Comment: @Billy: You might double-check that, as I'm quite sure that a C-style cast indeed can remove *cv-qualfiers*.

Comment: @Ben: Ah, I stand corrected. Thanks! I learned something today! *Notes standard 5.4 paragraph 4* :)

Answer (score 1):

Since `mvinstr` is actually storing data into the array pointed at by the `char*`, you can't use a `string` there.  You need to allocate an array of char, pass that to `mvinstr`, and then transfer the characters to a `string` if you want.

If you were using a function that could have been declared with a `const char *` (i.e. it doesn't actually modify the array), then you could use `const_cast<>` to remove the `const`.

```
const_cast<char *>(str.c_str());
```

But that's not what you're doing here.  `const_cast` might work if you tried it, but it would be by accident, not because it's supposed to work, and a new compiler or library version could break it at any time.

Comment: @Ben: No, I mean an array.  We're interfacing with C code here.

Comment: Yes, and a vector easily gives you a pointer which C code understands, and also frees the memory automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like the following, then use `buffer` wherever you need a `char*`. As Ben mentioned, you need to be very careful to keep the buffer larger than the string plus null terminator.

```
const int BUFFER_SIZE = 255;

string str ("Your string");
char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
if (str.length() < BUFFER_SIZE)
{
    size_t copy_length;
    copy_length=str.copy(buffer,str.length(),0);
    buffer[copy_length]='\0';
}
```

Comment: This is just asking to become an accidental buffer overflow.

Comment: Try using `mvinnstr(time_loc_y, time_loc_x, buffer, size);`, where `size` is no larger than the size of your buffer - 1. Your 12-character buffer is probably too small.

Answer (score 0):

Removing const can be done with `const_cast`, and is sometimes necessary for using legacy interfaces that were written in C and don't use const.  In such cases, you can do:

```
char* ptr = const_cast<char*> (str.c_str());
```

However, from the cplusplus reference page on [c_str](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/)():

> The returned array points to an internal location with the required storage space for this sequence of characters plus its terminating null-character, but the values in this array should not be modified in the program and are only granted to remain unchanged until the next call to a non-constant member function of the string object.

This means that it is your responsibility to ensure that `ptr` is **not** used to modify the string, and you **must** handle the lifetime of `ptr` appropriately.  I.e., you cannot continue to use `ptr` after `str` is out of scope, or after you call any non-const methods on `str`.  If you do that, you go into Undefined Behavior, and will likely crash.

If you are looking for a safe way to interact with a legacy interface that takes `char*`, you can make your own writable copy:

```
char* ptr = new char[ str.size() + 1 ];
strcpy(ptr, str.c_str());
ptr[str.size()] = '\0';
// ... use ptr as much as you want...
delete [] ptr;
```

Comment: `new []` and `delete []`?   Just use `std::vector`.

Comment: @Ben, how is a `vector<char>` supposed to help with using a legacy interface that expects `char*` as an input parameter?  A `boost::scoped_array` would work far better here.

Comment: `vector<char> vec = FillMeWithData(); legacy_c_function(&vec[0]);` Not so say `boost::scoped_array` isn't also an option.  So long as there's no raw pointers floating around.

Comment: @Dennis: Although, the data comes from the legacy c function.  So `vector<char> vec(str.size() + 1); legacy_c_function(&vec[0]);`

Answer (score -1):

`if (string.empty()) foo(const_cast<char*>(string.c_str());`

a better but still evil way to remove const is const_cast(const_string); (its better to find via grep/search)

Witch exception did you encountered?
Do u just read the char* or do you change the values? if you change, you should redesign your code.

`const char* test = string.c_str();`
Does not create a deep copy of string, only a pointer to the internal data representation of string.data().

=> (a suggestion) find a C++ book where you can get a more in deep view of c++. Or something like  to C++.